# How do you mount a USB Drive?

Tags: usb, mount

I have tried to mount my 32GB USB Drive for a while now. Every time I do, it tells me "mount: only root can do that"

HELP

Answer (score 0):

Become root with sudo.

`sudo mount <options> <device path> <mount location>`